# Accessing nested collections in velocity

Tags: java, loops, templates, nested, velocity

I have this velocity template:

```
<userTestData>

#foreach( $user in $userList )
<user>
    <imsi>$user.imsi</imsi>
    #foreach ( $subscriptionToGroupMap in $user.subscriptionToGroupsList )
    <subscriptionToGroup>
        #foreach ( $key in subscriptionToGroupMap.keySet() )
        <$key>$subscriptionToGroupMap.get($key)</$key>
        #end
    </subscriptionToGroup>
    #end
</user>

#end
</userTestData>
```

But when trying it I get the following error message:

```
16:23:58,872 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component ... for method public void ...) ...: javax.ejb.EJBException: org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Invalid arg #2 in directive #foreach at userTestDataTemplate.vm[line 10, column 21]
```

Which basically points to this line:

```
#foreach ( $subscriptionToGroupMap in $user.subscriptionToGroupsList )
```

The rest of the code looks like:

```
ArrayList userList = new ArrayList();

    for(...) {
        Map user = new HashMap();
        user.put("imsi", i);

        ArrayList subscriptionToGroupsList = new ArrayList();

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int numberOfSubscriptionsToGroups = (rnd.nextInt(1000) % (BucketType.values().length)) + 1;
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "...: numberOfSubscriptionsToGroups {0}", numberOfSubscriptionsToGroups);
        for(int j = 0; j < numberOfSubscriptionsToGroups; j++) {
            Map subscriptionToGroupMap = new HashMap();

            subscriptionToGroupMap.put("name", ...);

            subscriptionToGroupMap.put("priority", rnd.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE) % (Integer.MAX_VALUE));

            ...
            Date startDate = new Date(dateGeneratorHelper);
            String stringFormattedStartDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss").format(startDate);
            subscriptionToGroupMap.put("startDate", stringFormattedStartDate);

            Date endDate = new Date(dateGeneratorHelper + dateGeneratorHelperHelper + 1);
            String stringFormattedEndDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss").format(endDate);
            subscriptionToGroupMap.put("endDate", stringFormattedEndDate);

            subscriptionToGroupsList.add(subscriptionToGroupMap);                
        }

        user.put("subscriptionToGroupsList", subscriptionToGroupsList);

        userList.add(user);           
    }

    String debugOutput = null;
    for (Iterator it = userList.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        HashMap userMap = (HashMap)it.next();
        debugOutput += "\n" + userMap.get("imsi") + "\n";
        ArrayList stgsList = (ArrayList)userMap.get("subscriptionToGroupsList");
        for (Iterator jt = stgsList.iterator(); jt.hasNext();) {
            Map stgMap = (HashMap)jt.next();
            for (Iterator nt = stgMap.entrySet().iterator(); nt.hasNext();) {
                Map.Entry<String, ArrayList> entry = (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList>)nt.next();
                debugOutput += "\t<" + entry.getKey() + ">" + entry.getValue() + "</" + entry.getKey() + ">\n";
            }
        }
    }

    ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext)webServiceContext.getMessageContext().get(MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT);
    VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
    ve.setApplicationAttribute("javax.servlet.ServletContext", servletContext); 
    ve.setProperty("resource.loader", "webapp"); 
    ve.setProperty("webapp.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.tools.view.servlet.WebappLoader"); 
    ve.setProperty("webapp.resource.loader.path", "/WEB-INF/classes"); 
    VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext();
    velocityContext.put("userList", userList);
    Template t = ve.getTemplate("userTestDataTemplate.vm");
    StringWriter writer;
    writer = new StringWriter();
    t.merge(velocityContext, writer);
```

I get the right debug output from the piece of Java code so the info is there.

Do you have any idea why velocity doesn't accept the access to the list in the $user Map?

Comment: Is it a typo or is there is missing `$` at `#foreach ( $key in subscriptionToGroupMap.keySet() )` (should be `$subscriptionToGroupMap.keySet()`) ?

Comment: I don't have the code with me know so I can't check it, that would be embarrassing but a big relief at the same time.

So the code looks ok to you?

Comment: you should be able to get using
`$user.get("subscriptionToGroupsList")`
is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your velocity context contains one object "userList" which is a `List`, and you get your `$user` from it : ok. `$user` is a `Map` that in turn contains a list of maps.

So the error is normal : velocity uses the `.` notation to access methods of an object, or attributes of a bean, not elements of a map.

You must write :

```
#foreach ( $subscriptionToGroupMap in $user["subscriptionToGroupsList"] )
```

and except for the missing `$` to lines later (see my comment above), the remaining of the template looks ok (but I did not test it ...)

Comment: Now it works, with your suggestion, thanks very much. Btw, I was missing the '$' sign but I'd like to think I'd have fixed that when notified about the error.